# Form Validationn

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to create a simple form validation from an user input box. I'm trying to create an alert if the user does not enter anything into the text box. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="block3">
    <input type="text" name="form" id="FAQS_list"
           placeholder="Enter Number Here"/>
    <button value="Click" onclick="listFAQS()" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
        Click
    </button>
    <script src="expExternal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
function validateForm() {
    var y = document.getElementById("form").value;
    if (y == "") {
        alert("Please enter a number!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong here, but when the text box is left empty, there is no alert pop-up. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(y)` to see wh`y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this change:

```
var y = document.getElementById("FAQS_list").value;
```

The id of your input is FAQS_list and not name.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var y = document.getElementById("FAQS_list").value;
  if (y == "") {
    alert("Please enter a number!");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="block3"><br/><br/>
  <p id="p01">
    Enter a number (up to 3):
    <input type="text" name="form" id="FAQS_list" placeholder="Enter Number Here" />, and
    <button value="Click" onclick="validateForm()" onSubmit="return validateForm()">Click</button> to see that many Frequently Asked Questions.<br/><br/><br/></p>
  <p id="FAQS"></p>
  <script src="expExternal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I was certain it was something simple. I will accept as correct answer!

Comment: Glad to help you. If you liked the answer, could you please upvote it as well? Thanks.